# fill na by proportion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, fillna

I am trying the following code to fill missing values by proportion but this code isnt working, is there someone who can help me?

[image: Python Fill Value by proportion]
Click above to see screenshot

## testing missing values

```
df['Diarrhoea'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)
output: 
0.0    0.686439
1.0    0.238198
NaN    0.075363
Name: Diarrhoea, dtype: float64
```

```
df['Diarrhoea'].value_counts(normalize=True)
Output:
0.0    0.742388
1.0    0.257612
Name: Diarrhoea, dtype: float64
```

```
df['Diarrhoea'] = df['Diarrhoea'].fillna(pd.Series(np.random.choice(['0.0', '1.0'], 
                                                      p=[0.75,0.25], size=len(df))))
```

Now if i run the following command it shows me NaN values:

```
df[df['Diarrhoea'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Your code works well for me. At the end, I have no null values in `Diarrhoea` column

Comment: Can you see the attached screenshot? Is there any mistake which im doing? Please can you help

Comment: I don't see any error. Can you share your file?

Comment: You need to post the code here as text, edit it into your question. Not a link to an imgur screenshot, which will not be indexed or findable here, and a link is ephemeral and is likely to break in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem here is index alignment/mismatch.** You are trying to fill the missing values using a series which has a **range index** different from the index of your dataframe so there is no match and hence missing values are not filled.

The solution is to assign the index of dataframe to the series that you have created to fill the missing values:

```
pd.Series(np.random.choice(['0.0', '1.0'], p=[0.75, 0.25], size=len(df)), index=df.index)
#                                                                         --------------
```

Comment: #testing missing values 
df['Diarrhoea'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)

Output:
0.0    0.686439
1.0    0.238198
0.0    0.057390
1.0    0.017973
Name: Diarrhoea, dtype: float64

Why it is showing me 2 times 0 and 2 times 1?

Comment: Thanks the error has been resolved but now here its showing me 1 and 0 two times

Comment: You should fill with `[0.0, 1.0]` (floats) instead of `['0.0', '1.0']` (strings). That's where the duplicates are coming from.

Comment: @Ali `random.choice` is a distribution function which approximately sample the variables based on the given probabilities. It does not gaurante that you exactly have the ratio of number of zeros to number of ones as 3 / 1

Comment: @tdy Thanks! Numerical values makes more sense here.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Oh yeah, my comment was directed at Ali to explain why his `value_counts` is now counting two 1s and two 0s. I realize you just copied his original Series.

Comment: @tdy No worries :-)